# Problems with memory mapped files with father and children processes

Tags: c, memory, dictionary, memory-management

I have a program that has to use mmf to map a ppm image to memory and then, each child, will have to invert *row by row* the mmf. It says :"the MMF version will first have to create a copy of the image (and rename it to the destiny filename) and then execute the inversion on that copy." The semaphores are in the correct order too and according to the assignment too.

From this, I've coded and it gives me the correct output but this happens :S. I don't understand why but it's clearly not right:

```
(...)
Inverting row... 
Done || 
Inverting row... 
Done || 
Cleaning up...
Closing file pointers.
*** glibc detected *** ./MMF_inverter: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x093a0170 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b591)[0x28e591]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cde8)[0x28fde8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x292ecd]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(fclose+0x14a)[0x27eaaa]
./MMF_inverter[0x80497d5]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x239bd6]
./MMF_inverter[0x8048d01]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00125000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1569987    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.1.so
00125000-00126000 r--p 00014000 08:05 1569987    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.1.so
00126000-00127000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 1569987    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.1.so
00127000-00129000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00129000-00146000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1439060    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00146000-00147000 r--p 0001c000 08:05 1439060    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00147000-00148000 rw-p 0001d000 08:05 1439060    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00223000-00376000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1569962    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00376000-00377000 ---p 00153000 08:05 1569962    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00377000-00379000 r--p 00153000 08:05 1569962    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
00379000-0037a000 rw-p 00155000 08:05 1569962    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
0037a000-0037d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00459000-0045a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00471000-0048c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1440096    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
0048c000-0048d000 r--p 0001a000 08:05 1440096    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
0048d000-0048e000 rw-p 0001b000 08:05 1440096    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00905000-0090c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1569989    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt-2.11.1.so
0090c000-0090d000 r--p 00006000 08:05 1569989    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt-2.11.1.so
0090d000-0090e000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 1569989    /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt-2.11.1.so
08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1458241    /home/neverMind/Desktop/SO-TP2/MMF/MMF_inverter
0804b000-0804c000 r--p 00002000 08:05 1458241    /home/neverMind/Desktop/SO-TP2/MMF/MMF_inverter
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 1458241    /home/neverMind/Desktop/SO-TP2/MMF/MMF_inverter
093a0000-093c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7700000-b7721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7721000-b7800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b781c000-b7855000 rw-s 00000000 08:05 1458172    /home/neverMind/Desktop/SO-TP2/MMF/out.ppm
b7855000-b7857000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7862000-b7863000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 52069041   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)Aborted
```

Here is the code (run as ./invert input_filename.ppm output_filename.ppm) it has to be ppm:
[main](http://pastebin.com/ny7a2N5q)
[functions c file](http://pastebin.com/CE2dhXwA)
[header file](http://pastebin.com/JCeZrjG1)
[makefile](http://pastebin.com/DwHVH0Sy)

You can test it with this for example: [ppm image with p6 header](http://www.easy-share.com/1913048545/sketch.ppm)

I'm only mapping the file in the master process, before spawn children and make each child invert a row on that mapped file. Is this correct?

Comment: it looks you somehow corrupt memory, use valgrind to search for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other things, you are closing your file handles twice. Run your program under `valgrind`, as Drakosha suggested.

Comment: What flags do you suggest me to use? Because I've already tried a few ...and there was a looooooot of info. I'm newb ah this, sorry. I don't have a C compiler at hand right now. but I see the two fcloses. I've missed it. It always better to show somebody your code, I guess

Comment: Most of the callstacks you'll see come from the double fclose() error. Fix that and rerun, you'll see a lot less output. Iterate until there are no more errors left.

Comment: @neverMind: actually, I didn't look at your code. `valgrind` told me where the double-free error was.